# How can I get the same file with origin file even with same newlines in qt using the readline()?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to write a qt function to copy a file. However I cannot copy the truly same file because the '\n' cannot keep the same.

For example, My test code

```
void testFile()
{
    QFile inFile(":/testFile-ANSI-win.txt");
    if (!inFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return;

    QFile outFile("../testFile-ANSI-win-readline-bak.txt");
    if (!outFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Truncate))
        return;
    QTextStream in(&inFile);              
    QTextStream out(&outFile);
    out.setCodec("UTF-8");
    while (!in.atEnd())
    {
        QString line = in.readLine();    
        out << line;
        out << "\r\n";
    }
}
```

And my input file is:

```
11111
22222


33333
```

But my output file is:

```
11111
22222


33333
          // Fail to be the same. There is a new line, but I don't want it
```

When the input file ends with the empty line, the function works well. The output file is the same as the input file. And my input file is:

```
11111
22222
          // ends with the empty line
```

But my output file is:

```
11111
22222
         //  Same!!
```

Is it possible to copy the same file from the origin file using readLine() function?

Similar problem:

[using readAll the copy the same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49666753/how-can-i-get-the-same-file-with-origin-file-even-with-same-newlines-in-qt)

Comment: From the documentation:
`The returned line has no trailing end-of-line characters ("\n" or "\r\n")`
So you have no way of knowing whether the original file had a newline or not. If you really needed to, you could cheat and peek at the last few bytes of `inFile` by yourself, by `seek`ing to right before the end of the file.

Comment: Use the static function `QFile::copy` it will copy the file 1:1 on Windows. `QFile::copy("C:\input.txt", "C:\\out.txt");`

Comment: @user3606329 No, `QFile::copy` cannot copy the same file. I have test.You can test with my first test input. You will find the output have one more newline at the end of file.

Comment: @Botje I have read the official documentation. And the `peek` trick is not what I wanted. Thank you all the same.

Comment: @JosanSun are you aware that some editors (e.g. Geany) **show** a newline at the end of text files that are missing one?

Comment: Actually, the markdown is also the case. But I just want to keep the same file.

Comment: @ JosanSun: I just tested `QFile::copy` output is exactly as input without newline at the end on Windows 7. Perhaps your editor displays it not correct. I copy pasted and saved your input with notepad.exe.

Comment: @user3606329 Thank you for your feedback. And I find my problem. `QFile::copy` will generate a read-only file. I cannot write the same file again, if I just change the content of my input file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read all the input in a string, split the string into lines, output the lines inserting a newline **before** every line, after the first one.

Something like:

```
        QString all = inFile.readAll();
        QStringList lines = all.split('\n');

        QTextStream out(&outFile);
        out.setCodec("UTF-8");

        QString line;
        for(int i=0; i<lines.size(); i++)
        {
            if(i>0)
            {
                out << endl;
            }
            line = lines.at(i);
            out << line;
        }
```

You can do more or less the same traversing the stream, but an extra check is needed after the loop:

```
        QString line;

        QTextStream in(&inFile);
        QTextStream out(&outFile);
        out.setCodec("UTF-8");

        bool first = false;
        while (!in.atEnd())
        {
            if(first)
            {
                out << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                first = true;
            }
            line = in.readLine();
            out << line;
        }

        if(line.isEmpty())
        {
            out << endl;
        }
```

If the last read line was empty, the source file had a newline at the end, which has to be written.

Comment: Yeah. This is great!